# how to add id to pre tag from the closest li element with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to add an ID to a `pre` tag from the closest `li` tag in which is the `pre` tag:

So this is what I have now:

```
<li id="12345">
   <pre class="code">
      <!-- some code goes here -->
   </pre>
</li>
```

And it should become this:

```
<li id="12345">
   <pre class="code" id="12345">
      <!-- some code goes here -->
   </pre>
</li>
```

Comment: ids must be unique among all the dom elements

Comment: two html elements can't have same id, you can have `data-id="12345"`

Comment: but you can have class, which serves purpose, or as GeneR mentioned

Comment: yes I am using jquery. I am using this code: $('pre')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution with data-id instead of id:

```
$('pre').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-id', $(this).closest('li').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The elemnts id should be unique in the dom. Try appending some string to make it unique like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').find('pre').attr('id', function(d){  return $(this).parent().attr('id')+'_pre';  });
});
```

Comment: ok I understand the ID must be unique.Can I do something with stripping, because the li ID looks like this: id="Comment_12345" so strip Comment_ out of it and I have a unique id . but this needs to be added to the pre tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var test = document.getElementById("test");
  var pre = test.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];
  pre.id = "pre_" + test.id;
  console.log(pre)
})()
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <pre>Test Pre</pre>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('li').each(function(i)
        {
           var id = $(this).attr('id');
           $(this).find('pre').data('id',id);//for data-id
           $(this).find('pre').attr('id',id);//for id
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, id are unique keys and cannot be repeated. 
You should better add Class not id.

However, to answer your question, try the below code.

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('pre'); 
var y = x.parent;
x.setAttribute("id", y.id);
```